# How can I correctly read and save a bcrf file in Python using utf-16 encoding?

Tags: python, readfile, utf-16, writefile

I tried to read a *.bcrf file generated by SPIP tool and intended to save it back to a *.bcrf file as exactly same content as the original. But the results seems not going well.
Here is the link description of the bcrf file format: http://www.imagemet.com/WebHelp6/Default.htm#Reference_Guide/BCR_STM_File_Format.htm
The bcrf file I tried to read: [bcrf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o8KBKRIdfv3xkWXjAmKhq1-bJ_Koj4d4/view?usp=share_link)

```
import struct

def read_bcrf_file(filename):
    header_size = 2048
    data_size = 900 * 900 * 4  # Assuming 32-bit floating point data (bcrf format)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        # Read the header
        header = file.read(header_size)

        # Parse the header values
        header_dict = {}
        decoded_header = header.decode('utf-16').replace('\x00', '')
        for line in decoded_header.split('\n'):
            if '=' in line:
                key, value = line.strip().split('=')
                header_dict[key.strip()] = value.strip()

        # Read the data
        data = file.read(data_size)

    return header_dict, data


def convert_data_to_float(data):
    float_data = struct.unpack('<' + 'f' * (len(data) // 4), data)
    return float_data


def write_bcr_file(filename, header_dict, data):
    header_size = 2048

    # Create the header string
    header = ""
    for key, value in header_dict.items():
        header += key + " = " + value + "\n"

    # Pad the header to the required size
    header = header.ljust(header_size, '\x00')

    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        # Write the header
        file.write(header.encode('utf-16')[2:])

        # Write the data
        data_bytes = struct.pack('<' + 'f' * len(data), *data)
        file.write(data_bytes)


# Example usage
header, binary_data = read_bcrf_file('test_file.bcrf')
data = convert_data_to_float(binary_data)
write_bcr_file('new.bcrf', header_dict=header, data=data)
# Process the data as needed
```

[The new image is dislocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUn0T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

header = header.ljust(header_size, '\x00')
this line is wrong， try my code

```
import struct

def read_bcrf_file(filename):
    header_size = 4096
    data_size = 900 * 900 * 4  # Assuming 32-bit floating point data (bcrf format)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        # Read the header
        header = file.read(header_size)

        # Parse the header values
        header_dict = {}
        decoded_header = header.decode('utf-16le')
        for line in decoded_header.split('\n'):
            if '=' in line:
                key, value = line.strip().split('=')
                header_dict[key.strip()] = value.strip()

        # Read the data
        data = file.read(data_size)
    return header_dict, data


def convert_data_to_float(data):
    float_data = struct.unpack('<' + 'f' * (len(data) // 4), data)
    # print(float_data[:10])
    return float_data


def write_bcr_file(filename, header_dict, data):
    header_size = 4096

    # Create the header string
    header = ""
    for key, value in header_dict.items():
        header += key + " = " + value + "\n"

    # Pad the header to the required size
    header = header.ljust(header_size//2, '%')

    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        # Write the header
        file.write(header.encode('utf-16le'))

        # Write the data
        data_bytes = struct.pack('<' + 'f' * len(data), *data)
        file.write(data_bytes)


# Example usage
header, binary_data = read_bcrf_file('test_file.bcrf')
data = convert_data_to_float(binary_data)
write_bcr_file('new.bcrf', header_dict=header, data=data)
# Process the data as needed
```

Comment: This misreads the data because the header is actually 2048 UTF-16 code units (4096 bytes).

Comment: You are right, I change the header_size to 4096.

Answer (score 1):

The header is 2048 UTF-16 code units (4096 bytes).  There are some other minor differences like the header padding in the original file is `%` instead of a null byte (`\x00`) and a few of the original parameters didn't have a space on one side of the equals sign (`=`).  Also I used `array.array` as it is easier to construct the float data and corresponding bytes in this case than `struct.pack`:

```py
import array

HEADER_SIZE = 4096

def read_bcrf_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        # Read the header
        header = file.read(HEADER_SIZE)

        # Parse the header values
        header_dict = {}
        decoded_header = header.decode('utf-16le').rstrip('%')  # remove padding
        print(decoded_header)
        for line in decoded_header.split('\n'):
            line = line.strip()
            if line and not line.startswith('%'):
                key, value = line.split('=')
                header_dict[key.strip()] = value.strip()

        # Read the data
        data = array.array('f', file.read())

    return header_dict, data

def write_bcr_file(filename, header_dict, data):

    # Create the header string
    header = ''
    for key, value in header_dict.items():
        header += f'{key} = {value}\n'

    # Pad the header to the required size
    header = header.ljust(HEADER_SIZE // 2, '%')  # re-add padding...pre-encoding so use half header size in bytes

    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        # Write the header
        file.write(header.encode('utf-16le'))
        file.write(data.tobytes())

header1, data1 = read_bcrf_file('test_file.bcrf')
write_bcr_file('new.bcrf', header_dict=header1, data=data1)
header2, data2 = read_bcrf_file('new.bcrf')
print('headers same:', header1 == header2)
print('data same:', data1 == data2)
```

Output (with annotation):

```
fileformat = bcrf_unicode
headersize = 2048
xpixels =900                   # Original parameters did not
ypixels =900                   # have space after equals
xlength =313370.880126953      # on these
ylength =311383.331298828      # five
scanspeed =-1000               # parameters.
intelmode = 1
bit2nm = 1
xoffset = 0
yoffset = 0
voidpixels = 0
zmin = 0
xunit = um
yunit = um
zunit = um
forcecurve = 0

fileformat = bcrf_unicode
headersize = 2048
xpixels = 900                 # new file has spaces, but not important
ypixels = 900
xlength = 313370.880126953
ylength = 311383.331298828
scanspeed = -1000
intelmode = 1
bit2nm = 1
xoffset = 0
yoffset = 0
voidpixels = 0
zmin = 0
xunit = um
yunit = um
zunit = um
forcecurve = 0

headers same: True
data same: True
```